# Rails flash is missing eventually. Isn`t it thread-safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, thin, flash-message

I have Rails application running on Thin with multithreading. There is a bunch of polling requests and sometimes, when running integration tests concurrent I have about 1-2% of missing flash failures. In my `production.log` I have something like the following in case of failure:

```
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.280455 #2146]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://192.168.102.1/projects/599bcfd4875aa40862863a5b
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.282501 #2146]  INFO -- :   Rendered text template (0.1ms)
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.283151 #2146]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3062ms (Views: 1.4ms)
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.309004 #23906]  INFO -- :   Rendered projects/_tests_block.html.haml (24.0ms)
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.309392 #23906]  INFO -- :   Rendered projects/show.js.haml within layouts/application (29.9ms)
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.318025 #23906]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 48.4ms)
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.318956 #2146]  INFO -- : Started GET "/projects/599bcfd4875aa40862863a5b" for 192.168.102.2 at 2017-08-21 23:31:51 -0700
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.321849 #2146]  INFO -- : Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
I, [2017-08-21T23:31:51.321994 #2146]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"599bcfd4875aa40862863a5b"}
```

My redirect call looks like `redirect_to @project, notice: success_message`

Between redirect and start of getting show page I have the finish of polling request from another page. In this case when show page is rendered, there is no `flash[:notice]`.

I tried to keep and clear flash explicitly, so there is `before_filter { flash.keep }` in ApplicationController and `flash.clear` in my notification partial.

I also tried to log flashes before every action and in this concurrent case no another action steals flash, it's just missing.

Is this a multithreading problem? Or maybe I should use or implement flash with kind of "destination"? So that should be thread-safe too anyway.

PS Ruby 2.3.4, Rails 4.2.7, Thin 1.5.1

Comment: Yes, its threadsafe. Are you doing a redirect after you set flash key-value?

Comment: Flashes are stored in the users session and by default that is a cookie, so they have the limitations coming from that if the user agent (browser) is making multiple HTTP in parallel. Is it possible in your tests for the user agent to ever have multiple requests at once?

Comment: @FedeBonisconti I use short syntax and set flash as a parameter of redirect: `redirect_to @project, notice: success_message`

Comment: @FireLancer yes, the problem is when user agent send polling request and request to the action, which makes redirect